# QXmlSchema validation

Tags: qt, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to check the validity of an XML schema using methods provided by QXmlSchema.
I know from other tools (such as Eclipse or xmllint) that the schema *is* valid, but the outcome with the following code always results in "schema is invalid".

```
QFile file("/home/....xsd");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QXmlSchema schema;
schema.load(&file, QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName()));

if ( schema.isValid() ) {
    QXmlSchemaValidator validator( schema );
    if ( validator.validate( QUrl("file:///......xml") ) ) {
        qDebug() << "instance is valid";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "instance is invalid";
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << "schema is invalid";
}
```

The error logged is something like:

> Error XSDError in file:///home/......xsd, at line X, column Y: Content model of complex type foo is not a valid extension of content model of bar.

I wonder if this has to do with the Schema namespace imports or what else.

EDIT:
The schema I'm referring to is [this one](http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/schemas/EBUCore/20110915/EBU_CORE_20110915.zip).

Comment: Could you run your schema through the `xmlpatternsvalidator` tool (part of QtXmlPatterns) to check whether Qt can parse the schema?

Comment: Would you be able to pastebin the schema?

Comment: @skyhisi I have just tried and the error is the same. The schema is [this one](http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/schemas/EBUCore/20110915/EBU_CORE_20110915.zip).